# elasticsearch find fields containing value substring AND fields containing values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a dropdown search system, so that if i search for "walm" I will get results for "walmart".

This query will work:

```
GET /indexname*/_search
{
  "size":0,
   
    "aggs": {
        "by_filter": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "store_name.keyword",
            "size":1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "doc": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
   
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "store_name: 'walmart' AND (source: 'smartpakequine') AND product_gap.keyword: 'yes'"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "format": "date",
                    "gte": "2020-08-25",
                    "lte": "2020-08-27"
                  }
                }
              } 
            ]
          }
        },
      
      "sort": { "assortment_score": { "order": "desc" } }

}
```

But If i include partial strings for my query_string like :

```
"query": "store_name: 'walm' AND (source: 'smartpakequine') AND product_gap.keyword: 'yes'"
```

It will return zero results. If I change my query to only include a regex expression like so:

```
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "regexp": {
              "store_name": "walmart.*"
            },
           }
         ]
        }
      }
```

It works, but then I cant include my querystring for searching the other parameters. Same thing with a wildcard search, where I could only include the wildcard search and couldnt use my original query_string anymore. is there some way I can tell my query_string to include partial substring results for store_name?

```
"query": "store_name: 'walm' AND (source: 'smartpakequine') AND product_gap.keyword: 'yes'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding working example with index data, search query and search result.

Refer this [ES official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to get detailed explanation on Query string query

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "store_name": "wallmart",
    "product_gap":"yes"
}

{
    "store_name": "wallm",
    "product_gap":"yes"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string":
          {   "fields": ["store_name", "product_gap"],
              "query": "Wallm* AND yes"
          }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.1823215,
                "_source": {
                    "store_name": "wallm",
                    "product_gap": "yes"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.1823215,
                "_source": {
                    "store_name": "wallmart",
                    "product_gap": "yes"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: @Martin Hope you are doing well !! Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you resolve your issue?